# Same values different spot in memory

Tags: java

I'm trying to get one of my arraylists to have the same values as another one, but I don't want them to have the same place (same reference) in memory. Any quick ways on how to implement this? It's an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` that I'm trying to copy.

Comment: put the code :)

Comment: Try to break down the problem into smaller ones. 1) Create a new ArrayList. 2) iterate over each ArrayList in the original list-of-lists. 3) for each one, create a new ArrayList from that list, and add it to the copy list-of-lists. Each of those is a small, self-contained concept. Figure each one out, and you're almost there!

Comment: sounds like you want a deap clone. which can be done in a bunch of different ways with different efficiency. but if the structure is only ever ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> you might just want to write your own copy method.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new List object using the old list as parameter:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
```

for `List<List<String>>` try using:

```
 //yourList is the list with your old values
 List<List<String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(List<String> oldList : yourList){
   newList.add(new ArrayList<>(oldList));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I just used a for loop...

```
 ArrayList < ArrayList<String > > new2dArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList < String > > ();

  for(int i = 0; i < orig2dArrayList.size(); i++){

        ArrayList<String> newArrayList = new 
                ArrayList<String>();

        for(int j = 0; j < orig2dArrayList.get(i).size(); j++){


           newArrayList.add(orig2dArrayList.get(i).get(j));

        }
        new2dArrayList.add(newArrayList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work as well (Java 8):

```
List<ArrayList<String>> newList =

oldList.stream().map(ArrayList<String>::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**newList** contains new List objects, while strings remain the same (immutable anyway).